# font size discrepancy html/dreamweaver vs illustrator

Tags: html, fonts, size, dreamweaver

I'm sure I must be being a total eedyat somewhere and I've been fishing round for an answer but..

I'm finding a massive discrepancy in the way Dreamweaver is rendering font size (tried both pt and px with same issue) from photoshop and illustrator.

Linked to 3 screenshots of:
Georgia at 18pt in psd,
Georgia at 18pt in ai,
Georgia at 18pt as html /system text
(same issue with other fonts) 
(tried with both inline css and external css)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQVEq.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/roPRS.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGlKs.png]

Test code here:

```
<body >
<div style="font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:18pt;">
 This is a test this is a test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone put me right?

Answer (score 2):

html(browser) pt from W3.org states **px: pixel units — 1px is equal to 0.75pt.**

But Adobe product's pt to html(browser) css's coding is **1pt(photoshop) = 1px(css)**

So if you try to do **18px in css** instead of 18pt in css then you should be able to get the same text font.

See link: http://www.sherriwyche.com/tools/fontconversion.html

Answer (score 0):

All i can suggest is the font names if you understand fonts can be chosen by user agents(browsers) as the best "version" available. e.g. serif or arial e.t.c.

Also agents have text zoom settings and their own render engines for the fonts.

OS systems use(as in a user) fonts , so primarily its whatever is available of similar class of font. The complete font also is not always carried by an "AKA" user agent.

Comment: Thanks for your input. (I definitely have Georgia on my system and it looks to be the same/first choice font in the stack-just bigger pt size). I also tested in firefox/safari and chrome and got thee same size differentiation each time.