# Convert Adobe Illustrator font-size in css font-size

Tags: css, fonts, adobe

A web designer gave me a document that contains font-size and letter-spacing in px for the css (Desing realised in Illustrator). I'm looking for a way to convert the AI value in CSS value and keep ratio beetween elements. If i use the AI values in CSS, doesn't have the same look.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495139/font-size-discrepancy-html-dreamweaver-vs-illustrator?rq=1

Comment: I found how to use Illustrator's mesures in css. Like is said in related question, 1pt in Ai become 1px in css. And for the letter-spacing, the VA value have a 1000/1 ratio. In my case i have VA = 60 => letter-spacing: 0.06em.
And with that my web page have the same ratio looking  than the Ai file.